What are some logical arguments against miaphysitism?
The idea that Christ is of one divino-human nature.

Miaphysitism (/maɪˈæfɪsaɪtɪzəm, miː-/[1]) is the Christological doctrine that holds Jesus, the "Incarnate Word, is fully divine and fully human, in one 'nature' (physis)."[2] It is a position held by the Oriental Orthodox Churches and differs from the Chalcedonian position that Jesus is one "person" (Greek: ὑπόστασις) in two "natures" (Greek: φύσεις), a divine nature and a human nature (dyophysitism). Wikipedia - Miaphystism.

Since you asking for 'logical arguments' this becomes a philosophical question. Did you wish a scriptural response. ?

Related, possible duplicate what-are-the-major-problems-that-chalcedonians-have-with-miaphysite-christology.

This question would greatly benefit from explicit definitions of "divine nature" and "human nature". Otherwise, it's easy to interpret the terms in different ways, producing different answers.

My understanding is that Divine nature and human nature cannot 'merge' but are united in the Person of Christ. The union is in his Person, not in an attribute : 'nature'.
I assume that I would be referred to as a 'Chalcedonian'.
From my own point of view, therefore, as a Chalcedonian, the situation is not reconcilible. The concept of Divine nature and human nature being combined (merged) into one 'nature' is not logical and I can think of no scripture that would be useful for someone arguing that it is so.

Nigel, the dimo was asking for arguments against it not for. I agree with your point, a "third" nature  or merged one is not acceptable and really screws up a lot of understandings we have.

I I have not mentioned a 'third nature'. I have not given an argument 'for' miaphysitism. I have given an argument against it.

You are a Chalcedonian, you reject the "merged" nature. You referenced it in the first sentence of your answer. "I agree with your point, (A third nature, the result of miaphysitism) is not acceptable. We are in agreement. :)

Well we first need to understand the situation that caused Miaphysitism.... if you don't need all the context, the bottom 2 parts are more to the point.

The term "miaphysitism" arose as a response to Nestorianism. As
Nestorianism had its roots in the Antiochene tradition and was opposed
by the Alexandrian tradition, Christians in Syria and Egypt who wanted
to distance themselves from the extremes of Nestorianism and wished to
uphold the integrity of their theological position adopted this term
to express their position.
The theology of miaphysitism is based on an understanding of the
nature (Greek φύσις physis) of Christ: divine and human. After
steering between the heresies of docetism (that Christ only appeared
to be human) and adoptionism (that Christ was a man chosen by God),
the Church began to explore the mystery of Christ's nature further.
Having agreed that Christ is both divine and human, the first
difficulty was Nestorianism, which was perceived as stressing the two
natures of Christ to such an extent that it appeared, to opponents,
that two persons were living in the same body. Nestorianism taught
that Christ's humanity but not His divinity was born of the Virgin
Mary.
The reaction to this was monophysitism, which stressed that Christ has
but one single nature where the divine consumed the human as the ocean
consumes a drop of vinegar. This was called Eutychianism. Both of
these positions were seen as heretical, but the church remained
divided on how best to formulate a response to these. Cyril of
Alexandria's works were the basis of the stance of miaphysitism. He
spoke of the "one (mia) nature of the Word of God incarnate" (μία
φύσις τοῦ θεοῦ λόγου σεσαρκωμένη mia physis tou theou logou
sesarkōmenē) and a "union according to hypostasis" (ἕνωσις καθ'
ὑπόστασιν henōsis kath' hypostasin), or hypostatic union. The
distinction of this stance was that the incarnate Christ has one
nature, but that nature is of the two natures, divine and human, and
retains all the characteristics of both. However, opponents of those
who took this stance regarded it as nothing more than monophysitism.
The alternative response, which eventually became Byzantine dogma, was
dyophysitism. This states that Christ has two natures, but emphasizes
that they are not separated: Christ is fully one person (ὑπόστασις
hypostasis). The miaphysites regarded this as verging on Nestorianism.
The Council of Chalcedon (451) is often seen as a watershed for
Christology, as it adopted dyophysitism. However, as large portions of
the Church in Syria and Egypt, who held to miaphysitism, rejected the
decision, the controversy became a major socio-political problem for
the Byzantine Empire. There were numerous attempts at reunion between
the two camps (including the Henoticon in 482), and the balance of
power shifted several times. However, the decision at Chalcedon
remains the official teaching of the Eastern Orthodox Church, the
Roman Catholic Church and traditional Protestants. The
non-Chalcedonian Orthodox Churches are usually grouped together as
Oriental Orthodox. Over recent decades, leaders of the various
branches of the Church have spoken about the differences between their
respective christologies as not being as extreme as was traditionally
held.
Much has been said about the difficulties in understanding the Greek
technical terms used in these controversies. The main words are ousia
(οὐσία, 'essence'), physis (φύσις, 'nature'), hypostasis (ὑπόστασις,
'concrete reality/person') and prosopon (πρόσωπον, 'mask/person').
Even in Greek, their meanings can overlap somewhat. These difficulties
became even more exaggerated when these technical terms were
translated into other languages. In Syriac, physis was translated as
kyānâ (ܟܝܢܐ) and hypostasis was qnômâ (ܩܢܘܡܐ). The shades of meaning
are even more blurred between these words, and they could not be used
in such a philosophical way as their Greek counterparts. Hence, some
have suggested that miaphysitism came about due to a grounding of
language in the fact that someone's person and nature are a
verisimilitude.

-Kinda a shameless copy and pasted part from the Orthodoxwiki

Miaphysitism holds that Christ has one nature that is both divine and human. Duophysitism holds that Christ has two natures, one divine, and one human.
Duophysitism is the position that was dogmatized at the Council of Chalcedon, and is the Orthodox position.
We would hold that a divine-human nature is, ultimately, a third nature, distinct from divine nature and human nature, and, because "that which is not assumed is not healed," such a teaching would mean that we are not healed by Christ's incarnation, because he does not share our nature, not to mention the questions this raises in regards to the Son's relationship with the Father.
Thus, we hold that Christ must have had a fully divine nature (light from light, true God of true God, of one essence with the Father) and a fully human nature, assuming our humanity so as to heal it, neither of which is mixed or blended, and neither of which is compromised at all by their union in the one hypostasis of the Son.

So the logical argument you are seeking is that a third nature would throw everything we understand into chaos. How are we saved? How does Theosis work? How was human nature changed? What exactly is Jesus if he is something else in essence? etc.


What are some logical arguments against miaphysitism?

The best argument is to properly define the terms being used, and then to show that the very idea of fully having divine and human nature at the same time is contradictory.
The word "nature" here is a translation of the Greek "physis", which occurs in only 11 Bible verses, sometimes translated as "natural".
Its primary meaning is "the nature of things, the force, laws, order of nature", a definition that is self-referential because the meaning is so obvious, as in Romans 11:24's the olive tree which is wild by nature".
The expression "divine nature" itself occurs only once in scripture, 2 Peter 1:4:

Whereby are given unto us exceeding great and precious promises: that by these ye might be partakers of the divine nature, having escaped the corruption that is in the world through lust.

Clearly, the term "divine nature" isn't used here as a major doctrinal concept, but simply a reference to the nature of God, as opposed to the nature of mankind.
People may have turned "divine nature" into a significant term, and created many other related terms (e.g. "miaphysitism"), but really it isn't a thing.
There is a vast difference between the two natures (i.e. the normal thoughts and behaviours of God and of humans):

Isaiah 55:8: "For my thoughts are not your thoughts, neither are your ways my ways, saith the LORD."
John 10:10 (NLT): "The thief’s purpose is to steal and kill and destroy. My purpose is to give them a rich and satisfying life.".

Consider human nature (i.e. how humans naturally think and behave):

Romans 8:7: "Because the carnal mind is enmity against God: for it is not subject to the law of God, neither indeed can be."
Titus 1:15: "Unto the pure all things are pure: but unto them that are defiled and unbelieving is nothing pure; but even their mind and conscience is defiled."

Lesson 8: God's Commitment to Change Our Nature:

Two major factors shape all that is wrong with human nature.

First is the fundamental weakness inherent in our fleshly body and mind.
Our thoughts and emotions are directly linked to our fleshly impulses and desires.
We are born with them.
But we are born with neither the knowledge nor the power to properly manage them.
Second, our natural impulses and desires are often affected and even manipulated by external pressures.
Adverse influences arise from many sources—familial, educational, recreational, cultural and spiritual, to name a few.
But they have one thing in common: They tempt our basic instincts and desires.


God's many other attributes can be found throughout scripture, usually contrasted with the opposite human attribute.
Briefly, God's way is one of give, not of get.
As 1 John 4:16 simply tells us, "God is love".
God's nature and human nature are very different.
As a physical human being, Jesus gave up all his divine attributes, except for his divine character and personality.
As a physical human being, Jesus was subject to fleshly impulses and desires, and was subject to external temptation (e.g. by Satan, and even by Peter); he took on human nature and became capable of choosing to sin.
But, like all fully baptized and converted Christians, he had a communications channel available: God's holy spirit provided communication with God, supplying advice, strength, and guidance.
At his resurrection, Jesus was converted back into a perfect immortal spirit being, no longer retaining any of his temporary human nature.
He did have personal experience of what it is like to be human, but as the first human to be reborn as a son of God his nature was now identical to God's nature.
Any discussion of whether Jesus (or anyone) can fully have divine and human nature at the same time is pointless.
Human nature is the susceptibility to sin; if one has human nature, even a little, then by definition one cannot fully have divine nature.
The incarnate Jesus did have a fully human nature, but now he has a fully divine nature, as will all humans that will be reborn as his siblings.

Perhaps candidly point out your denominational foundation. It appears like you are advocating for some type of Monophysitism?
